# How to limit layer output(activation) value in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to limit the range of the output in tensorflow, and **make sure the gradient can pass through those clipped values**, for example:

```
y = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
```

I want to limit the value of y, so that y can be in range (-2, 2)

I have tried:

```
y = tf.clip_by_value(y, -2, 2)
```

But gradients can't pass through those clipped values in y, they get 0 gradients.

**EDITED:**

**Below is the real distribution of my cnn layer output：（What I want is to limit those outliers' value, for the reason that they make latter RNN layer saturate）**

[real distribution of my cnn layer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0HqR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Functions like clip etc. are not differentiable in certain regions. So don't expect gradients to behave well.

If all you want to do is limit the value of y to a range [-2, 2], then it is better to use a tanh activation function. Set y = 2*tanh(x).

Comment: Thanks！ What I want is to limit those outliers' value in CNN layer output, for the reason that they make latter RNN layer saturate(I add a tensorboard distribution now). I didn't try tanh because I think there would be no gradient pass through those outliers if tanh function is saturated as well. Maybe I should just scale them by some factor or use a piecewise linear function?